# No QoS Event Callbacks for services in ROS2

Tags: ros2

rclcpp had publisher and subscriber event callback function for qos settings (https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/p/rclcpp/generated/structrclcpp_1_1SubscriptionEventCallbacks.html ) but there are no such callback functions for the qos settings for services. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!